# SQL CONSTRAINT different name

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I have two databases with the exactly the same table but they are different with regards to CONSTRAINTs. Look at the picture below for detail.

[image]

As you can see, `SRO_VT_SHARD_188` has a CONSTRAINT for `_RefObjChar` but `SRO_VT_SHARD_D9` doesn't have one.

I have deleted table `_RefObjChar` in `SRO_VT_SHARD_D9` and recreated it with a query wich has full of CONSTRAINT, but I get this error:

> There is already an object named 'DF__RefObjChar_Resist27' in the database.

I know if I change CONSTRAINT's name to `DF__RefObjChar_Resist27AAA`, my query can run without error but I was wondering that if I do that, does it make any query error or something not work because old CONSTRAINT's name is changed?

Comment: Constraint names are database wide. Or schema wide. Or something like that; different to index names at any rate. `DF_TableName_ColumnName` and you'll be fine - just like foreign keys: `FK_ForeignTable_PrimaryTable`.

Comment: But if I change the name like `DF_TableName_ColumnName_SomeString` it will be fine too?

Comment: There should not be any problem with your query if you change the constraint's name (I think you will need to drop and re create it). Unless you have some kind of query that change the structure of the data model in normal operation which will touch these constraints (highly unlikely, and I cannot any reason why there should be).

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, constraints are database wide. You don't even know if the constraint in question is defined on this particular table. Run the query below (or similar) to find out where the constraint is used. It is always preferable to name your constraints declaratively, also as noted in the comments, rather than letting them be named by the system or by a tool. I tend towards `<schema>__<object>__<column>__<type>`. So this would be [dbo__SRO_VT_SHARD_DN__df]. Now your constraint name clearly indicates where and how it is used. Note that I use a double underscore to separate schema, object, column, type, because a single underscore is often used in names. You might use a different notation. The point is to make the naming as obvious as possible. Is [address_state_city_type_df] for schema [address_state] and table [city] column type, or for schema [address], table [state_city], etc.

```
select [default_constraints].[name]
       , [objects].[name]
       , [objects].[type_desc]
       , [columns].[name]
from   [sys].[default_constraints] as [default_constraints]
       join [sys].[objects] as [objects]
         on [objects].[object_id] = [default_constraints].[parent_object_id]
       join [sys].[columns] as [columns]
         on [columns].[column_id] = [default_constraints].[parent_column_id]
where  [default_constraints].[name] = N'DF__RefObjChar_Resist27';
```